# intellisense.annotate a function with a dynamically created annotation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense, annotate

I have a function `$.publish` to publish a list of functions by binding the first argument to `this`, and I'm intending to use it for writing `X.prototype`, for example:

```
X.prototype = (function () {
    function privateFunction(me) {
        /// <summary>privateFunction</summary>
        /// <param name="me" type="X"></param>
    }
    return $.publish({
        publicFunction: function (me, a) {
            /// <summary>publicFunction</summary>
            /// <param name="me" type="X"></param>
            /// <param name="a" type="Number"></param>
        }
    })
})();
```

So I can use `X` like

```
var x = new X;
x.publicFunction(0);
```

The implementation of `$.publish` in file `lib.js` is

```
publish: function (fs) {
    return $.map(fs, function () {
        var f = this;
        return function () {
            f.apply(/* irrelevant */);
        }
    })
}
```

.

## Problem

When I type `x.publicFunction(`, the signature help only tell me that `publicFunction()`, not knowing the param `a`.

The [MSDN doc - Adding IntelliSense Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874692.aspx#Annotations) says we can annotate a function like:

```
intellisense.annotate(someFunc, function (a) {
    /// <signature>
    /// <summary>Description of someFunc</summary>
    /// <param name="a">Param a</param>
    /// </signature>
});
```

So I wrote the following code in the `lib.intellisense.js`:

```
$.publish = function (fs) {
    /// <summary>Publish a list of functions</summary>
    /// <param name="fs" type="Object">List of functions to publish</param>

    return $.map(fs, function () {
        var f = this;

        var published = function () { };
        //intellisense.redirectDefinition(published, f);

        var funcSrc = f.toString();
        var vsdocPattern = /^([ \t]+)(\/{3} .*)/mg;
        var indent = -1;
        var vsdoc = "";
        for (var doc; (doc = vsdocPattern.exec(funcSrc)) != null;) {
            if (indent < 0) {
                indent = doc[1].length;
            } else if (indent != doc[1].length) {
                break;
            }
            if (doc[2].indexOf("<param name=\"me\"") > 0) {
                continue;
            }

            vsdoc += doc[0] + "\n";
        }
        if (vsdoc != "") {
            vsdocPattern.lastIndex = 0;
            var funcHeader = funcSrc.substr(0, funcSrc.search(vsdocPattern));
            funcHeader = funcHeader.replace(/(\(\s*)me(, )?/, "$1");

            var annotation = "(" + funcHeader + vsdoc + "})";
            //intellisense.annotate(published, eval(annotation));
            return eval(annotation);
        }

        return published;
    })
}
```

The result I get here is showing param `a` when I type `x.publicFunction(`, but the documents in the vsdoc are missing. I want the signature help to show the documents as well as the type info of the params, without repeating myself to copy and adjust the documents from `x.js` to `x.intellisense.js`, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of hiding the first few arguments in the intellisense for DesignTime, using `Function.prototype.bind` is enough.

So my solution is to update the `lib.intellisense.js` with the following code:

```
$.publish = function (fs) {
    /// <summary>Publish a list of functions.</summary>
    /// <param name="fs" type="Object">List of functions to publish</param>

    return $.map(fs, function () {
            var published = this.bind(null, null);
            intellisense.redirectDefinition(published, this);
            return published;
    })
}
```

No need to care about how to annotate the published function now, the M$ guys did it for `Function.prototype.bind` already.